# is it possibel to create a USDC liquidity pool with Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc20

I would like to develop a smart contract that can accept USDC deposits from users into a pool for further downstream activities and give them another token in return so that they can track their balance etc..

Has anyone any exampled/tutorials of something like this I could follow ?

Comment: Do you talk about something like what uniswap is doing ?

Comment: Well, kin dof I guess.. in so far that it would return a liquidity token in return after each deposit. But unlike uniswap it would do a bunch of other things underneath the hood